# SQL: How to force the relational operator to consider NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have 2 tables (TABLE1 & TABLE2). I would like to execute the below query:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a,TABLE1 b
SET a.desg=CASE WHEN b.attribute_id=74 THEN b.value ELSE a.desc END
WHERE a.entity_id=b.entity_id;
```

But i have some rows in TABLE1 with entity_id as NULLs.
These are not being considered while evaluating `WHERE a.entity_id=b.entity_id;`

I want even the NULLs to be considered for this WHERE clause.

How can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably the two references to `TABLE1` is a typo?

Comment: How many records in TABLE2 (or whichever is aliased as `b`) have a null `entity_id` and `attribute_id=74 ` ?  I hope it's one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use something like

```
WHERE IFNULL(a.entity_id, 0) = IFNULL(b.entity_id, 0);
```

Comment: Another solution is also `WHERE COALESCE(a.entity_id, 0) = COALESCE(b.entity_id, 0);` which returns the 1st occurence of a NON NULL value.

Comment: Make sure that there are no entities which actually have `entity_id=0` when using this method.

Comment: @PeterLang Thanks, Peter! That is why I said "something like"

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a, TABLE1 b
SET a.desg = CASE WHEN b.attribute_id=74 THEN b.value ELSE a.desc END
WHERE a.entity_id=b.entity_id OR (a.entity_id IS NULL AND b.entity_id IS NULL)
```